# Order of CSS in a style tag

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I had a quiz in a html/css class I'm taking asking me to use media queries to reorganize some divs based on screen size. The code they supplied that I was supposed to add onto was this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  /*
  These are the responsive styles. Throw some breakpoints in here!
  */
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .box {
    width: 100%;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .dark_blue {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
</style>
```

There was a lot more than that but that is the relevant part. I came up with this:

```
<style type="text/css">
  /*
  These are the responsive styles. Throw some breakpoints in here!
  */
  @media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
   .light_blue, .green {
    width: 50%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
    .red {
      width: 33.3%;
    }
    .orange {
      width: 66.6%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .container {
      width: 800px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  }

  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .box {
    width: 100%;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .dark_blue {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
</style>
```

But it did literally nothing. The page was completely unchanged. I eventually gave up and looked at the answer, they had written exactly the same the CSS that I had, only in a different order:

```
<style type="text/css">
  /*
  These are the responsive styles. Throw some breakpoints in here!
  */
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .box {
    width: 100%;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 450px) {
   .light_blue, .green {
    width: 50%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 550px) {
    .red {
      width: 33.3%;
    }
    .orange {
      width: 66.6%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .container {
      width: 800px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .dark_blue {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
</style>
```

So my question is, how does order get applied here and why didn't my code do anything at all?

Comment: what you want to try? post some html and explain little bit more so we can help you in proper way..

Answer (score 1):

CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheets, so there rules will be interpreted cascading down, so if you have

```
.blue { color: blue; }
```

And then later on down the same CSS file, you put

```
.blue { color: pink; }
```

It will overwrite the `color` of `.blue` to `pink`

With media queries you want to add your default styling first and then add your media queries, because it will detect media queries first and then just use those rules instead of your default styling.

Because the browser will be able to detect (for example) your devices `min-width` is `800px`, it'll pick up those styles and not bother to overwrite them when the file gets interpreted further down in your default styling

Hard to explain. Hope that sort of cleared things up